# What is correct way to handle large cmake c++ dependencies pulled from source?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have quite a big cross-platform C++ project managed by cmake, with several big and small dependencies.

I have noticed that if i just compile each dependency along-side with my main project using `add_subdirectory` command in CMakeLists.txt, even if we take into account that cache is used in 99% of those builds (because i don't modify dependencies) linking process still takes longer compared to dynamic linking when i just install targeted dependencies system wide with apt-get (for example) and exclude those from ```add_subdirectory`` command.

What is correct way to solve that issue, considering that i want my project to be fully cross-platform, .e.g just `git pull && git submoduless init && cmake . -DCMAKE_...` on any supported platform without the need of manually fetching each library i need on each platform?

In other words are there any methods to tell cmake to pre-build each dependency library on targeted platform before first build if those are not found on target system, and make it available to my code without use of `add_subdirectory` but with use of `find_package`, which i assume just links dynamically existing libraries.

Comment: `pre-build each dependency library on targeted platform before first build if those are not found on target system,` These are called "packages" and are installed by "package managers" specific to the target system. So vendors provide "package repositories" that come with the software and all dependencies, targeted for the systems they want to support. For example: https://repo.zabbix.com/

Comment: you shoud get famliar with Conan or Vcpg

Comment: Just use [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io) and don't over-engineer this.